# NumPy. Problems creating a matrix by adding rows

Tags: python, numpy

I would like to build a matrix by adding the rows, starting from:

```
[ 5 20 31 32 36  3 10 25 27 40]
[ 3 10 25 27 40 18 19 20 40 41]
[18 19 20 40 41  6 22 26 29 48]
[ 6 22 26 29 48  8 11 23 27 35]
```

to get:

```
[[ 5 20 31 32 36  3 10 25 27 40],
[ 3 10 25 27 40 18 19 20 40 41],
[18 19 20 40 41  6 22 26 29 48],
[ 6 22 26 29 48  8 11 23 27 35]]
```

using this code:

```
#initialize the target matrix
arr = np.empty((0, 10), int)

for current_line in statistics.values:
    if len(previous_line) > 0:
        #build an array row of 10 elements by 2 array with lenght 5
        row = np.append(np.array(previous_line), np.array(current_line))

        #arr = np.append(arr, row, axis=0)   
        #fails with following Exception ValueError: all the input arrays must have same number of dimensions

    print(row)

    previous_line = current_line
```

print(row.shape) gives (10,) back. I tried using row.T but it fails as well.
Have you any suggestion?

Thank you very much!
Bye
Fabio

Comment: What is `previous_line`?  You create `arr` but don't use it.  Same for `row`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.append.html):

> It must be of the correct shape (the same shape as arr, excluding axis). If axis is not specified, values can be any shape and will be flattened before use.

Try to just add square brackets:

```
arr = np.append(arr, [row], axis=0)
```

In this case, the number of dimensions for `arr` and `[row]` will be the same.

Answer (score 0):

Starting with a copy-n-paste of your start

```
In [418]: vstr = """[[5 20 31 32 36  3 10 25 27 40]
     ...: [3 10 25 27 40 18 19 20 40 41]
     ...: [18 19 20 40 41  6 22 26 29 48]
     ...: [6 22 26 29 48  8 11 23 27 35]]"""
In [420]: vstr=','.join(vstr.split())
In [421]: vstr
Out[421]: '[[5,20,31,....]]'
In [422]: vlist=json.loads(vstr)
In [423]: vlist
Out[423]: 
[[5, 20, 31, 32, 36, 3, 10, 25, 27, 40],
 [3, 10, 25, 27, 40, 18, 19, 20, 40, 41],
 [18, 19, 20, 40, 41, 6, 22, 26, 29, 48],
 [6, 22, 26, 29, 48, 8, 11, 23, 27, 35]]
```

I now have a list of lists.

The easiest way to make that into an array is just pass it to `np.array`

```
In [424]: arr=np.array(vlist)
In [425]: arr
Out[425]: 
array([[ 5, 20, 31, 32, 36,  3, 10, 25, 27, 40],
       [ 3, 10, 25, 27, 40, 18, 19, 20, 40, 41],
       [18, 19, 20, 40, 41,  6, 22, 26, 29, 48],
       [ 6, 22, 26, 29, 48,  8, 11, 23, 27, 35]])
```

If the source of those sublists is some process, do

```
alist=[]
for line in vlist:
    alist.append(line)
arr = np.array(alist)
```

Using array `append` is possible, but slower, and you have to be careful with dimensions.  `append` is just `concatenate` that takes 2 arguments, and makes sure they are at least 1d.  It's really meant for adding one value to end of an array.

Here's what you should be doing if using a row by row concatenation:

```
arr = np.empty((0,10),int)
for line in vlist:
    arr = np.concatenate([arr, np.atleast_2d(line)],axis=0)
```

`arr = np.append(arr, np.atleast_2d(line), axis=0)` also works, but obscures the essential details. So does `arr = np.vstack((arr, line))`. There are other ways of turning `line` into the required 2d array. `[line]` that `@SphDev` suggests is another.